# How do I remove node in Linked List?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am implementing Linked List by using Python. Here is my code

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, newElement):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = newElement
        else:
            self.head = newElement
    #get position time complexity O(n)
    #get the node at a specific position
    def get_position(self, position):
        current = self.head
        current_pos = 1
        while current_pos <= position:
            if current_pos == position:
                return current
            current = current.next
            current_pos += 1
        return None
    #Insert element
    # Time complexity O(n)
    def insert_element(self, element, position):
        if position > 1:
            front_pos = self.get_position(position - 1)
            end_pos = self.get_position(position + 1)
            front_pos.next = element
            element.next = end_pos
        else:
            element.next = self.head
            self.head = element
    def delete_element(self, element):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            if current.value == element:
                if not previous:
                    self.head = element
                previous.next = current.next

            else:
                current = current.next
                previous = current

        else:
            return False


node1 = Node("Iron Man")
node2 = Node("Capitain America")
node3 = Node("Doctor Strange")
node4 = Node("Spider man")
node5 = Node("Rieder")
print("Node1 Value is {}".format(node1.value))
print("Node1 next Value is {}".format(node1.next))
print("Node2 Value is {}".format(node2.value))
print("Node2 next Value is {}".format(node2.next))
Avengers = LinkedList()
Avengers.append(node1)
print("Firt element in link list is {}".format(Avengers.head.value))
Avengers.append(node2)
print("After Iron Man is {}".format(Avengers.head.next.value))
print(Avengers.get_position(2).value)
Avengers.append(node3)
Avengers.append(node4)
Avengers.insert_element(node5, 4)
print(Avengers.get_position(4).value)
Avengers.delete_element(node5)
print(Avengers.get_position(4).value)
```

Here is my output:

```
Node1 Value is Iron Man
Node1 next Value is None
Node2 Value is Capitain America
Node2 next Value is None
Firt element in link list is Iron Man
After Iron Man is Capitain America
Capitain America
Rieder
Rieder
```

The list structure link like this: Ironman -> Capitain America -> Doctor Strange -> Rieder -> Spiderman

Therefore, if I do not want the "Rieder" node. The last line of output should show "Spider man"

What happened in my code? Really appreciate for people who help me out :D

Comment: `print(Avengers.get_position(5).value)` after `Avengers.insert_element(node5, 4) ` and you will find something is also wrong with insert_element`  function.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you appear to update `current` and then update `previous` with the new value of current.  I would go back to your `delete` method, and go through it line by line.  It helps if you write out on paper what the state of your list is at each line, and see if you can correct the algorithm.

```py
else:
    current = current.next
    previous = current
```

Comment: I think "current" actually need to be updated right? Because you need to traverse all the way down

Comment: What I'm saying is that the way you have it right now, when this else executes, I think previous becomes the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your `insert_element` function. You are inserting nodes incorrectly. This is the correct way to do it

```
def insert_element(self, element, position):
        if position > 1:
            front_pos = self.get_position(position - 1)
            # end_pos should not be position + 1, because it will
            # skip the element at index=position
            end_pos = self.get_position(position)
            front_pos.next = element
            element.next = end_pos
        else:
            element.next = self.head
            self.head = element
```

Next, you need to only pass the value of the nodes and not the nodes themselves while deleting the elements. I have made some minor changes to your code to fix some bugs. See the comments for more information

```
def delete_element(self, element):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            if current.value == element:
                # This means that the head itself
                # has to be deleted
                if not previous:
                    self.head = self.head.next
                # Add an else block correctly here
                # in case head is not to be deleted
                else:
                    previous.next = current.next
                # break the loop when the element is deleted
                break

            else:
                # First copy the current into previous,
                # Then change the value of current
                previous = current
                current = current.next
```

Also there is no need for `else: return False` block at the end of delete function.